# Plugin.LocalNotification doesn't build in Release Mode

Tags: maui

I try to add LocalNotification to the application, everything works in Debug mode, but when I change to Release mode, notifications do not work.
Anyone know how to deal with it?

```
using Plugin.LocalNotification;

namespace TestNotif;

public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .UseLocalNotification()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });

        

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

I got this error CS1061:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS1061  'MauiAppBuilder' does not contain a definition for
> 'UseLocalNotification' and no accessible extension method
> 'UseLocalNotification' accepting a first argument of type
> 'MauiAppBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
> an assembly reference?)   TestNotif (net6.0-maccatalyst), TestNotif
> (net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0)  C:\Users---\source\repos\TestNotif\TestNotif\MauiProgram.cs    14  Active

```
using Plugin.LocalNotification;
using System;

namespace TestNotif;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    int count = 0;
    

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NotificationGet();
    }

    public async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var notification6 = new NotificationRequest
        {
            BadgeNumber = 1,
            Description = "Test Description",
            Title = "Notification!",
            ReturningData = "Dummy Data",
            NotificationId = 1327,
            Schedule =
            {


                NotifyTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5)
            }

        };
        await LocalNotificationCenter.Current.Show(notification6);
    }
```

Comment: You are saying that you get compiler errors only in Release mode but not in Debug mode for the same code?

Comment: @Jason yes, that's weird.

Comment: have you compared all of the project options for the two different build configs?

Comment: I didn't change anything in the options.

Comment: Because this plugin is not built-in to Maui, please include a link to the plugin you are using. Is this https://github.com/thudugala/Plugin.LocalNotification?  If so, looking at it, it only supports Android and iOS. the Release build attempts to build for all included configurations; error message shows failure on Windows and MacCatalyst. It might have built Android OK; look in bin/Release.

Comment: Yes, it is this one plugin. Maybe is the way to make it on IF ANDROID?

Comment: Its generate release version, but there dosnt work notifications. On debug version still working.

Answer (score 0):

Fix #1: Only build for Android, to avoid errors when Maui attempts to build release for MacCatalyst and Windows:

- Rt-click your Maui project, "Properties".
- Application > General, find "iOS Targets > Target the iOS platform: Enable targeting of the iOS platform. UNCHECK.
- Similarly find and UNCHECK: Windows Targets > Target ..: Enable targetting of the Windows platform.

Fix #2: Notifications don't work on Android:

- Test on an actual device, not on an emulator.

---

If after both of these, it still doesn't work, then contact author of that plug-in for help.